# override onClick and also using the default onclick

Tags: android, webview, onclick, super

I overriden the onClick(View) method, so that on click the view size will change.
The View is a webView that shows a browser web page.
I need that the click will change the size, but also that the browser will respond (Go to the Link that was clicked). In the current situation the user have to click twice - one for the size change and the other is for the respond of the browser, and thats not good enough.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

this is my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {

    case R.id.button2:
        // If web2 is pressed the Relativelayout who contain the webView will
        // take this parameters
        lin1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 8));
        lin2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));
        butt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        butt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        lin1.bringChildToFront(butt1);
        break;

    case R.id.button1:
        // If web2 is pressed the Relativelayouts who contain the webView will
        // take this parameters

        lin2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 8));
        lin1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));
        butt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        butt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lin2.bringChildToFront(butt2);
        break;
    }
    return ;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using super.onClick()?

Comment: using super.onClick() gets a compilation error of undefined method

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think that the proper way to add an event to a view isn't using a switch, why don't you try something like this:...So this will be your listener for the view, I hope to help

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

//and your custom code is going to be here                  

}
});
```

Comment: I cant use a button, I need that any click on the view's area will make the code run

Comment: I put an example with a button because you have buttons in your code, to a different view check the others listeners like .setOnTouchListener, setOnLongClickListener, setOnHoverListener or add new callback to your view! greats

Comment: Will doing it like you suggested allow me to both change display and get response from browser? I still have to override the onClick meyhod

Comment: Hi  J Sanchez, I did it your way, but it didn't change a thing... same problem

Comment: Hi, happy new year! I don't get the whole idea about your issue to show an activity with a web view you need to create an Intent in order to show it, and in the code for the webview activity you need to specify the attributes for example:

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_1);  
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    web.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.yourContentPage.com/"); 
    }

Comment: and with the method web.loadUrl(String address) in OnCreate Activity you declare your main website to load! hope to help